# How to calculate the shortest path?

Tags: java

I implemented a code to calculate the shortest route,but i want to add a condition.If i got a matrix like this :

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 B 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How can i add a condition that from cell A to cell B it can move only if there is a distance of one row or one column of 0 , so the shortest path from A to B (A is on [4;0] and B is on [5;5]) is : [4;0] , [5;0] , [6;0] , [7;0] , [7;1] , [7;2] , [7,3] , [7,4] , [7,5] , [6,5] , [5;5] .
This is what i have at the moment:

```
   import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ShortestPathBetweenCellsBFS {

    private static class Cell  {
        int x;
        int y;
        int dist;   //distance
        Cell prev;  //parent cell in the path

        Cell(int x, int y, int dist, Cell prev) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.dist = dist;
            this.prev = prev;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
        }
    }


    public static void shortestPath(int[][] matrix, int[] start, int[] end) {
        int sx = start[0], sy = start[1];
        int dx = end[0], dy = end[1];


        int m = matrix.length;
        int n = matrix[0].length;       
        Cell[][] cells = new Cell[m][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] != 1) {
                    cells[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, Integer.MAX_VALUE, null);
                }
            }
        }

        LinkedList<Cell> queue = new LinkedList<>();       
        Cell src = cells[sx][sy];
        src.dist = 0;
        queue.add(src);
        System.out.println(src);
        Cell dest = null;
        Cell p;
        while ((p = queue.poll()) != null) {
            //find destination 
            if (p.x == dx && p.y == dy) { 
                dest = p;
                break;
            }

            // moving up
            visit(cells, queue, p.x - 1, p.y, p);

            // moving down
            visit(cells, queue, p.x + 1, p.y, p);

            // moving left
            visit(cells, queue, p.x, p.y - 1, p);

            //moving right
            visit(cells, queue, p.x, p.y + 1, p);
        }

        if (dest == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            LinkedList<Cell> path = new LinkedList<>();
            p = dest;
            do {
                path.addFirst(p);
            } while ((p = p.prev) != null);
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    }

    //function to update cell visiting status
    static void visit(Cell[][] cells, LinkedList<Cell> queue, int x, int y, Cell parent) { 
        if (x < 0 || x >= cells.length || y < 0 || y >= cells[0].length || cells[x][y] == null) {
            return;
        }

        int dist = parent.dist + 1;
        Cell p = cells[x][y];
        if (dist < p.dist) {
            p.dist = dist;
            p.prev = parent;
            queue.add(p);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
       int[][] matrix = {
           {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
       };
       int[] start = {4, 0};
       int[] end = {5, 5};
       shortestPath(matrix, start, end);       
    } 
}
```

Comment: Someone wrote a paper about the different algorithms you can use to calculate the shortest route, maybe this paper can be of use to you. You can freely download it here: https://science.vu.nl/en/Images/werkstuk-pepping_tcm296-107124.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of one possible solution would be to only add cells to the queue of your pathfinding algorithm if they have a distance of at least one to any wall.

So for example in your `visit` method, you would have to check all the neighbouring cells as well instead of only `cells[x][y]`.

One way to do this would be to loop over the neighbouring cells and abort, when you find a cell that is an obstacle.

```
for (int x_test = Math.max(0, x - 1); x_test <= Math.min(cells.length - 1; x + 1); x_test++) {
    for (int y_test = Math.max(0, y - 1); y_test <= Math.min(cells[0].length - 1; y + 1); y_test++) {
        if (cells[x][y] == null) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I am using `Math.min` and `Math.max` in the loops to prevent out of bounds accesses.

Comment: I must verify and add to the queue in this segment of code  if (dist < p.dist) ... ?